# Occasional "Failed to create system events window thread." from `SystemEvents.TimeChanged`

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

I have a Windows service that spawns some child processes that sometimes gets an exception on some machines when adding a [`SystemEvents.TimeChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged?view=netframework-4.8.1) handler ([reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/microsoft/win32/SystemEvents.cs,286)). If it did fail it seems to fail repeatedly on that machine until possibly next restart, but only when running as a service (running the same exe with the same command line from command prompt then still works).

It seems to work most of the time and I never got it to happen on my own machines or in a debugger.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: Failed to create system events window thread.
at Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.EnsureSystemEvents(Boolean requireHandle, Boolean throwOnRefusal)
at MyApp..ctor() in C:\Myapp.cs:line 200
```

Where I think [`SystemEvents` throws](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/microsoft/win32/SystemEvents.cs,586):

> ```cs
> if (requireHandle && systemEvents.windowHandle == IntPtr.Zero) {
>     // In theory, it's not the end of the world that
>     // we don't get system events.  Unfortunately, the main reason windowHandle == 0
>     // is CreateWindowEx failed for mysterious reasons, and when that happens,
>     // subsequent (and more important) CreateWindowEx calls also fail.
>     // See ASURT #44424 for a rather lengthy discussion of this.
>     throw new ExternalException(SR.GetString(SR.ErrorCreateSystemEvents));
> }
> ```

Other GUI programs and services seem to work fine on that machine so I don't think anything is breaking `CreateWindowEx` in general.

```cs
SystemEvents.TimeChanged += new EventHandler(TimeChangeHandler); // Line 200
```

Can it have something to do with how I spawn the child processes not being able to properly create windows?

```cs
var info = new ProcessStartInfo(exePath)
{
    Arguments = commandLine,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true
};

childProcess = Process.Start(info);

childProcess.ErrorDataReceived += LogChildOutput;
childProcess.OutputDataReceived += LogChildOutput;
childProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
childProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

childProcess.Exited += ChildExited;
childProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Comment: Yes, that can happen.  A service runs with an intentionally small desktop heap.  Probably not a handle leak since this code ought to run early, when there are other services that consume too much of it then CreateWindow can fail.  Look [here](https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000086192-windows-service-quota-limits-and-desktop-heap-exhaustion).

Comment: Btw, the user can identify the troublemaker with Task Manager, Details view.  Add the "User Objects" column.

Comment: @HansPassant That could make sense, they are running a very large number of SYSTEM services. If I understand correctly the desktop heap is a fixed size per user shared between all processes of that user? The "dynamic allocation" referred to in newer Windows versions is only to allow more users, not a single user to have more things? So moving some services to another user account (e.g. NT SERVICE\foo) would give them more space?

Comment: The desktop heap is associated with a session.  Session 0 for services, all of them, distinct from the user's session.